# Visual basic number counting

Tags: .net, vb.net

i am in a bit of a pickle with this one, i need to change @CBANI (the result) according to number length that was input (@ANI),

*if number length is more than 10 then @CBANI has to be @Prefix + 00 + @ANI

*if number length is less than 10 then @CBANI has to be @Prefix + @ANI

(@CBANI has to be string value in the end)

lets say that stock values are

@ANI = 37253268578 (this is a phone number and can be without country prefix like that: 53268578)

@Prefix = 878

@CBANI = (blank because it will be determined after script has ran)

Current code is:

```
imports System
imports SMScriptBox
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

<Serializable()> Public Class Script
Sub New()
End Sub
Shared Sub Main()

    FlowContext.SetResult(0)  

    Try

        Dim sFilename As String
        Dim sNumber As String = FlowContext.GetVariable("@ANI")
        Dim sPrefix As String = FlowContext.GetVariable("@Prefix")        
        sFilename = sPrefix + sAni
        FlowContext.SetVariable("@CBANI", sFilename)

      Catch
      End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Fantastic. What have you tried so far? Also, a _succinct_ question please...

Comment: well a succinct question would be : 
now the code adds just prefix to phone number, but it needs to add 00 between prefix and phone number IF phone number is longer than 10 numbers, i hope i express myself correctly here :)

Comment: Could you not just use `If sNumber.Length > 10 Then sFilename = sPrefix & "00" & sAni Else sFilename = sPrefix & sAni End If`? Or something to that effect. What happens if the length is 10? You haven't said what the `sFilename` should be in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a prefix if the telephone number is longer than 10 characters you can use a ternary operator, as below

```
sFilename = If(sNumber.Length > 10, sPrefix & "00" & sAnsi, sPrefix & sAni)
```

Or in C# flavour

```
sFilename = sNumber.length > 10 ? sPrefix + "00" + sAnsi : sPrefix + sAni;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this one worked, now i feel kinda silly that i didnt think of it myself :)

Comment: You're welcome. Mark as corrected and upvote if it helps. Ternary operators are very useful for things like this :)

Comment: Cannot upvote Atm, reputation is too low, but marked as correct and thank you again :)